# Recommendations for setting ERC20 token totalSupply and decimals?

Tags: solidity, tokens

Looking through the Ethereum.org [token tutorials](https://ethereum.org/token).Any advice or recommendations on setting your total supply and decimals?

Inline comments says:

> 18 decimals is the strongly suggested

Any specific reason for this?

```
uint8 public decimals = 18;
// 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it

uint256 public totalSupply;
```

Any thoughts here would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

18 decimals is a popular choice because it's the number of decimals in ether. (1 ether == 10^18 wei.) Because it's so popular, you may encounter code that incorrectly assumes 18 decimal places.

It's entirely up to you what you choose, but I believe that's why most people stick with 18.